# showing that 2 matrices are not similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

There are two $3\times 3$ matrices:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
2 &-1 &-1\\ 
0& 1 &1\\ 
0 &0 &2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1 &1\\
 0& 1 &1\\
 0& 0& 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I need to show that these are not similar. They have the same determinant, rank and trace. I've tried to subtract with a matrix of the form $xI$ so that $x$ is a real number but that didn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use MathJax! See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have corrected the notation for you

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Comment: @marco11 You corrected what now? Seeing as the only editors of this question are me, Casteels and aepound, what do you mean by "I have corrected the notation"?

Comment: @5xum I corrected it **before** Casteels did, but he introduced his own edit, simultanously rejecting mine.

Comment: @marco11 I see now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. Look at the rank of $A - 2I$ and $B- 2I$.

Comment: I have no idea how i've missed this, thanks !

Comment: In this example, can we calculate the eigenvectors of one matrix to construct a change of basis matrix and then compare it with the second matrix?

Comment: @marco11 We can. But there is now need to, when we start to compare the eigenspaces, we see that the $2$-eigenspace of $A$ is one-dimensional, while the $2$-eigenspace of $B$ is two-dimensional.

Comment: @martini Because in case of $A$ for eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ the eigenvector is $(1,0,0)$ and in case of $B$ for eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ the eigenvectors are $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$. Am I right?

Comment: @marco11 You are right.

Answer (score 2):

this is what we get by row reducing the two matrices 
$A-2I = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 &-1 &-1\\ 
0& -1 &1\\ 
0 &0 &0
\end{bmatrix} \to  \begin{bmatrix} 
0 &1 &0\\ 
0& 0 &1\\ 
0 &0 &0
\end{bmatrix}$  and

$B-2I = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 &-1 &1\\ 
0& -1 &1\\ 
0 &0 &0
\end{bmatrix} \to  \begin{bmatrix} 
0 &1 &-1\\ 
0& 0 &0\\ 
0 &0 &0
\end{bmatrix}$

so that the null space of $A-2I$ has dimension one and the null space of $B-2I$ has dimension two. that is the matrices $A$ and $B$ are not similar.